# fetching webpage through java

Tags: java, tree, html-parsing, html, xml-parsing

I need to fetch a given web page, and then convert the HTML tag to XML tag, and from these XML tag i need to build a tree. how can i do that ?? please show me some good link or tutorial based on these, btw i am using the java language.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to write any code yet at all? HTML often contains invalid hierarchical XML content. This is not going to be an easy task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) to get the data.
[HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) to turn it into XML.

Both have tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apache http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ and http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/